# Создать программно ui элементы из файла

Tags: xcode, ios, ios7

Всем привет!
Хочу создать программно разные ui элементы (button, label, ...) во view controller. По нажатию на разные кнопки, в следующем окне должны создаваться разные элементы на своих заранее прописанных позициях. Вопрос такой: Как мне лучше хранить позиции, стили, тип ui элемента: в sqlite, plist, core data? Или предложите свой вариант. Просто таких окон может быть много, не хотелось бы для каждого создавать отдельный view controller, т.к. они по смыслу одинаковы, только у всех разные опции (у кого то например есть кнопка, у кого-то два text field, все ни расположены на разных позициях ). Или всё таки лучше для каждого свой view controller вручную создать?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что лучшим способом будет подготовить xib файлы или котроллеры в сториборде с нужными элементами, а по нужным кнопкам просто показывать нужный и уже готовый контроллер, то есть использовать стандартный подход, ведь контроллер из IB это и есть данные о позициях элементов и экшенах, только в xml.

Если все-таки решите создать супермегаконтроллер, который на вход принимает данные о UI элементах, а на выходе кодом создает свой layout, не забудьте про логику, например после ввода в 2 текстфилда нужно сделать то-то и то-то, а вот если текстфилд один, тогда уже вот это. Не думаю, что удастся создать абсолютно универсальный класс, а в IB это делается быстро, я уже не говорю о случаях какой-либо пусть даже легкой кастомизации. Тем не менее, для такой задачи я бы хранил данные в обычных plist ах.

Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо за инфу!

Answer (score 0):

согласен с [[[[@iFreeman](/users/16210/ifreeman)](/users/16210/ifreeman)](/users/16210/ifreeman)](/users/16210/ifreeman) на счет создать "котроллеры в сториборде с нужными элементами"

А можно и так (создать программно разные ui элементы):

```
CGRect myViewFrame = ...; //задаешь нужный фрейм
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myViewFrame];
myView. ; //тут задаешь параметры для свойств самой вьюхи, например myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

или добавим кнопку:

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];  
myButton.frame = cgframe; // сюда подставляешь нужный фрейм  
[myButton setTitle:btnLabelText forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//ну там на кнопку много чего еще можно задать
[self.view addSubview:myButton];
```

еще раз скажу, что поддерживаю [[[[@iFreeman](/users/16210/ifreeman)](/users/16210/ifreeman)](/users/16210/ifreeman)](/users/16210/ifreeman)

п.с. Еще очень советую обратить внимание на Container View http://take.ms/tGK57 эта штука принимает фрейм вьюхи, в которую ты его добавил, а потом создаешь разные ViewController, которые с ним связаны и они будут иметь тот же фрейм. Смысл в том, что как только ты поменяешь фрейм контейнера, то все вьюхи привязанные к нему автоматом поменяются. Но это так, для развития скорей, а не решения твоей задачи. А еще constraint очень нужная штука для автолайаута. Вобщем советую пользовать сториборд.